# Accessing NestedScrollController(in order to scroll to a certain element) in tabView inside NestedScrollView

Tags: flutter, dart, scroll, tabs

I have a brainer here. So I have a NestedScrollView with a header consisting of an image, and 3 tabs. Those 3 tabs, when scrolled, needs to be pinned to the top.

Visualization here:
[image]

Below I Have a tabView corresponding to tabs in a header. Those tabViews have dynamic height and all "tiles" are different. It's working. But I need to (onTap) change the tab and scroll to an element in the body of tab2.

**Problem:**
When trying to attach scroll controller to tab x body, the scrolling is independent from the global one.

When trying to use `PrimaryScrollController.of(context)` it works, but only on the first time. When I try to open it the second time I get **ScrollController attached to multiple scroll views** when switching to the different items (presented visualization can be multiplied for other items in the app). I tried to detach the current scroll position form the controller on dispose but I get another error.

Any ideas?